# Populate cell with name of the sheet which is the row's data source

Tags: vba, excel

I am pulling information from several sheets in my Excel file.

I want to fill out a column based on which sheet the information on that row comes from.

For example:

If data on Sheet B was taken from Sheet A, value of SheetB.ColumnE(SourceSheet) should be "A" OR "B"

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

    'set your sheets here
    Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers")
    rowCntr = 1

    'get last rows from both sheets
    lastRowInput = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = inputWS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'copy data from columns A, B, E, G, I, J, L and M
    inputWS1.Range("A4:A" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("B2")
    inputWS1.Range("B4:B" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("C2")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  
End Sub
```

My current code is pulling info from sheet Universal onto sheet Carriers. I want to place on column E the word "Universal".

I will do more sheets and I assume I'll be able to use the same code to provide them the name on Column E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'copy data from columns A, B, E, G, I, J, L and M
inputWS1.Range("A4:A" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("B2")
inputWS1.Range("B4:B" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("C2")

outputWS.Range("E2:E" & (lastRowInput-2)).Value = inputWS1.Name '<< add name
```